# How convert NSIndexPath to Int in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need the index of a cell of my `UICollectionView`. I know how get it, but the problem is when I convert this `NSIndexpath` to `Int`. This is my code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
    let index = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)!

    let vc : VideosViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! VideosViewController
    vc.id_category =  self.result_category[index.row as Int]["id"].intvalue
}
```

Comment: Are you firing the segue when a user selects a cell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to convert the `index.row` to `Int`, it's a `Int` already, see the declaration of Apple:

```
var row: Int { get }
```

In the class `NSIndexPath`.

Just do `vc.id_category =  self.result_category[index.row]["id"].intvalue`. Just be careful with the `index of out bound` in the array.

I hope this help you.